# Conditional average of variables in Pulp optimization problem

Tags: python, conditional-statements, average, pulp

Suppose I have 2 pulp variables: `x1` and `x2`. These two variables represent water temperatures inside two different water pipes. These two pipes, at a certain point, merges into one single pipe and the two water flows mixes together. The water temperature after the mixing is equal to the average of the two temperatures because the flow rate is the same.

If the flow of one water pipe is zero, there is no mixing and the output temperature is equal to the temperature of the non-zero flow water temperature.

This final water temperature is then used into the objective function of the pulp problem to calculate some cost.

This means that I have to calculate the average of these two variables but each variable has to be considered in the calculation of the average only if it is greater than 0.

Here is an example you can reproduce to calculate the average without the condition of `>0`.

```
from pulp import *

# Define the variables
x1 = LpVariable("x1", 0, None)
x2 = LpVariable("x2", 0, None)
avg = LpVariable("avg",0,None)

# Define the problem
prob = LpProblem("average_problem", LpMinimize)

# Define the objective function
prob += 0, "objective function"

# Calculate avg value
prob += avg==(x1+x2)/2, "average_constraint"

# Set x1 and x2 value just as example
prob += x1==100
prob += x2==50

cost_of_engine = (105-avg)*3/0.2

total_production_cost = lpSum(cost_of_engine+10)

prob.setObjective(total_production_cost)

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()
```

This example works if `x1` and `x2` are both higher than zero.

However, if for instance `x1=0` and `x2=100`, then `avg=50`.
What I need, instead, is to discard the `x1` variable from the calculation of the average so that `avg=100`.

This is clearly a non-linear problem because the denominator of the calculation of the average is dynamic and depends on the value of the variable `x1` and `x2`.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Maybe using the Big M technique?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a little context to what you want to **do** with the average?  If you just want to compute it from model parts, that is pretty straightforward...  If you want to **use it** in the model in an objective or constraint and the denominator is variable (like in your case, it is the number of non-zero variables), that is non-linear and problematic

Comment: Thank you AirSquid. I added more information in the post. And yes, I need to use the average in the model objective, which makes the problem non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches that might be reasonable, depending on the characteristics of your problem that are not described....  As noted, if you are trying to minimize an average in the objective and both the numerator *and* the denominator are variables, the resultant expression is non-linear and you'll need to consider a substitute objective or move outside of `pulp` and look at non-linear formulations and non-linear solvers.

##### Idea #1:  Use a penalty for the number of items used.

You can introduce (and properly constrain with a big-M constraint) a new variable `y_i ∈ {0, 1}` that is 1 if `x_i` is used and some logical weight `w` and use an objective like:

```
obj = ∑ x_i + w * ∑ y_i  ; minimized
```

which might work OK if the `x_i` are in a range such that a logical `w` can be generated.

Or...

##### Idea #2:  Use a mini-max or maxi-min constraint

If you are seeking an aggregate total of the `x_i` used, while minimizing the number that are used and there is some "trade space" in the model, you can set the objective to "maximize the minimum used `x_i` value", which might work, again, depending on the other characteristics of your model.  This should have similar effect by encouraging the model to pick larger `x_i` to make the target value.  In that case, you can...  In pseudocode:

Introduce `y` and `z` ...

```
y_i ∈ {0, 1}
x_i <= y_i * M

z ∈ Reals
z <= x_i + (1-y_i)*M     # constrain z to the lowest x_i used...

obj = max(z)
```

Comment: Hey @AirSquid, I will try to apply your Idea #2. In the meanwhile, I improved the description of my problem

Comment: If you just want to formulate a constraint on the average, that is linearizable (in general).  If you want to put it in the objective, you need to consider other options.  Your added info does both.  If you have a "target value" for the average, you could constrain it and remove it from the objective and just count which flows to use or such...that could be linear.